# set highlighted selected item in custom list view android

Tags: android, listview, background

I am using custom list view in my project.
When I click on item in `ListView` then that item should be hightlighted.

For this is used code in `listadapter`

```
@Override
public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    SubCategoryHolder holder = null;

      if (row == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
           row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
           holder = new SubCategoryHolder();
           holder.dishName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.subcat_name);
           row.setTag(holder);
      }else {
               holder = (SubCategoryHolder) row.getTag();
      }
      final SubcategoryGetSet sub = objects.get(position);
      holder.dishName.setText(sub.getDishName());
      holder.dishName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));


      row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setSelected(true);
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000e0"));  
        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

When i click  item then it is hilighted to blue.
The problem is it remains highligheted when i click another item .
How to remove background color of previous selected??

Comment: Hello Nilesh Patil ,Plese correct the answer if you find it usefull...

Comment: I set background when click .But the problem is that when I  click on another item ,previous item remain highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it helps.

```
        Integer lastSelectedItemPos;//to store last selected view position

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            SubCategoryHolder holder;
            if (row == null) {
                holder = new SubCategoryHolder();
                //your inflating stuff and find views
                //setOnClickListener for your layout
                holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        int pos = (int) view.getTag();
                        final SubcategoryGetSet sub = objects.get(pos);
                        sub.setSelected(true);//new item selected
                        if (lastSelectedItemPos != null) {
                            sub = objects.get(lastSelectedItemPos);
                            sub.setSelected(false);// dis select previous one
                        }
                        lastSelectedItemPos = pos;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();//refresh views
                    }
                });
                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (SubCategoryHolder) row.getTag();
            }

            holder.layout.setTag(position);//set  position as tag to your layout
            final SubcategoryGetSet sub = objects.get(pos);
            //your other stuff

            if (sub.isSelected())
                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);//selected color
             else
                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);//not selected color

            return row;

        }

        class SubCategoryHolder{
            //other views
            LinearLayout layout;
        }
    };
```

you need to create one extra field under `SubcategoryGetSet`

```
class SubcategoryGetSet{
    //your other objects, getters and setters
    boolean selected;
    public boolean isSelected() { return selected; }
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) { this.selected = selected; }
}
```

you need to add one more extra view as child of root view

```
<!-- root view (whatever your view is I am using LL )-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!-- add this view as sub child of root view and set listener for this -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--your other views/adapter design goes here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this the simplest solution for me.
In your xml file in the ListView description just add
the following attribute with whatever color you wish:

```
android:listSelector="@color/colorBlue"
```

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry! I don't know how to print code in this style.